# What's proper way of escaping input string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, escaping, graphql, graphql-js

See graphql mutation with JavaScript variables injected *(please ignore that it's constructed manually and not through some gql helper)*:

```
mutation {
  createPost(
    name: "${name}",
    description: "${description}" 
  ) { id }
}
```

Is there any standard function for escaping `name` & `description` string variables ?

Eg. some function `gqlEscape` which will make query safe:

```
mutation {
  createPost(
    name: "${gqlEscape(name)}",
    description: "${gqlEscape(description)}" 
  ) { id }
}
```

How would that function look like?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing string interpolation, you can use GraphQL variables which are designed for your use case. You can do this using raw HTTP, too, but I usually use [graphql-request](https://github.com/graphcool/graphql-request) in this case.

Here's an example:

```
import { request } from 'graphql-request'

const mutation = `
  mutation newPost($name: String!, $description: String) {
    createPost(
      name: $name,
      description: $description 
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
`

const variables = {
  name: 'New Post',
}

request('my-endpoint', mutation, variables).then(data => console.log(data))
```

A few notes:

- I defined two variables, `name: String!` and `description: String`. `String!` means, it's a *required* variable of type String, while `String` means it's an optional variable. You can see that I did not pass a value for `description`, which is possible because it's optional.
- I did *not* specify the double quotes for the two strings, that's already handled by the GraphQL Variables themselves.
- You can read more about GraphQL Variables [here](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables) and [here](https://www.graph.cool/docs/faq/flexibility-and-control-with-graphql-variables-thaexex7av/).

Comment: Thanks, looks like GraphQL Request library did the job. I was just curious how it works internally - but as looking into graphql-request code, there is just used JSON.stringify.. So probably in my initial example it might be possible to run `name: ${JSON.stringify(name)},` and it might just work.. // but you are right, that's not really proper way of doing it